# TranslateTransition jumps over a few pixels

Tags: animation, javafx-2

When i click and the animation begins, the image jumps from point A a quarter of the distance it should go and then runs just fine untill it reaches point B does anyone know why?

This is my methot i use for the image movement:

```
public void sky(Node node, double xDest, double yDest) {

    TranslateTransition tTrans = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.seconds(4), node);

    // tTrans.setFromX(xPlec);
    tTrans.setToX(xDest);
    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    // tTrans.setFromY(yPlec);
    tTrans.setToY(yDest);
    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    node.setLayoutX(node.getLayoutX() + xDest);
    node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + yDest);

    tTrans.play();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set end point for you node before starting transition? Try next code:

```
tTrans.setFromX(node.getLayoutX());
tTrans.setToX(xDest);
tTrans.setRate(2);
tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

tTrans.setFromY(node.getLayoutX());
tTrans.setToY(yDest);

tTrans.play();
```

Also note you don't need to call `setRate` and `setInterpolator` two times.

Comment: if i try your code when i click the move button the image will dissappear from where it is it will appear somewhere on the bottom right of the screen and then go to the specified coordinates, so it doesnt do that i have this        node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + yDest); but this jumps frames

Comment: i found the problem, the problem is that my button if i press it once it does not move images but it changes the coordinates of the images and when i press it the second time then it works and it moves the image 2 times the distance it should and i dont know why it does this.